# Display post time according to timezone name (yii)

Tags: php, date, datetime, yii, timezone

I am working on a social app and I want to display time of post according to the user's location timezone. I have used timezone like **Asia/Calcutta**. Now I want if someone is posting from USA then I should get date according to **Asia/Calcutta** time zone.
in `config.php` I set

```
  $timzone=isset($_COOKIE['goalsurf_timezone'])? $_COOKIE['goalsurf_timezone'] : 'America/Los_Angeles';
date_default_timezone_set($timzone);
```

And I have a function:

```
function gplustime($date)
{
    $time=strtotime($date);
    $dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($this->timezon)); //first argument "must" be a string
    $dt->setTimestamp($time); //adjust the object to correct timestamp
    return $dt->format(yii::app()->params['dateformat'].' h:i A');
}
```

In database, date is saving according to the user's location. But when I am displaying that date, it is displaying date as it is in database. Please help

**Update**
Also tried this:

```
function gplustime($date)
{
    $date = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone($this->timezon));
    return $date->format(yii::app()->params['dateformat'].' h:i A');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use the same time zone for all datetimes stored in the database, e.g. UTC and convert it to viewer's timezone on render:

```
$dt = new \DateTime($dateFromTheDB, new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dt->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone($viewerTimeZone));
return $dt->format(yii::app()->params['dateformat'].' h:i A');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii Forum may be help you

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/63546-sql-serverimplicit-conversion-from-data-type-varchar-to-varbinarymax-is-not-allowed-use-the-convert-function-to-run-this-query/

also in sql you use `CONVERT_TZ` function to change datetime according to timezone.

```
SELECT `groupId`, CONVERT(`name`, CHAR(255)) as `name`, `image`, `type`, `status`, CONVERT_TZ(`addedDate`,'-6:00','".$zone."') as `addedDate` FROM `msg_user_group` WHERE `groupId` = 1;
```

In this sql query i use CONVERT and CONVERT_TZ 
Convert change the column datatype and CONVERT_TZ change the date time to one timezone to another

```
    CONVERT_TZ(`addedDate`,'-6:00','".$zone."')
'addedDate' => field name
'-6:30' => my current time zone
'$zone' => here put your timezone in which datetime format is change


SELECT `groupId`, CONVERT(`name`, CHAR(255)) as `name`, `image`, `type`, `status`, CONVERT_TZ(`addedDate`,'-6:00','+5:30') as `addedDate` FROM `msg_user_group` WHERE `groupId` = 1;
```

In this sql query i change timezone from -6:00 to +5:30

Comment: no need to do this . just set your default date as PST and use this  http://codingbin.com/display-local-time-according-to-visitors-location-with-javascript-and-php/